# Bootstrap tabs on hover with clickable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am using bootstrap tabs functionality and I would like to implement the following features:

1. Use mouseenter instead of click to toggle between tabs
2. To prevent clicking action on links.

Here is my jsfiddle sample code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/irider89/bmLpwtqb/3/

```
$('.nav li a').hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show');
});

$('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
    return true;
});
```

How this could be achieved?

I need to be able click on mainmenu items (Home, Profile, Messages, Settings) and go to the specific url.

Comment: What is the issue/question?

Comment: Your JSFiddle seems to work in a proper way, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to be able click on mainmenu items (Home, Profile, Messages, Settings) and go to the specific url.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use `window.location.href = ...` method! Middle mouse click will not work.**

---

**1) Toggle on hover.** Bind a simple mouseenter handler on the document object:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function () {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

---

**2) Prevent clicking.** It's better to use `.off('click', ...)` method to reset Bootstrap built-in handler instead of writing custom click handler dealing with custom data attribute. Like so:

```
$(document).off('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]');
```

Then use native `href` to specify external link and `data-target` to point to the content pane.

---

Also there is a small Bootstrap plugin which does all of that *automatically*: https://github.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs.

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/tonystar/pen/QbOByO)

Comment: hey in the plugin "mouseenter.bs.tab.data-api" is used, what does the appendage mean? if i wanted to add also focus, would be "focus.bs.tab.data-api" correct?

Comment: Correct! This is event namespacing (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#namespacing-events). Also you can combine both with space.

Answer (score 1):

Use some new "data-" attribute to mention the url, like this below

```
<a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-href="www.google.com">Home</a>
```

and use the script like this

```
 $('.nav li a').on("click",function (e) {
          window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-href");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to go the url:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
   window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but in in this case, if in nav links I will add a link instead of id, mouseenter functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I want to say that I still need to be able to use tabs functionality on hover and to be able to click on navs links too.

Comment: So you want to toggle tabs using "mousenter" as well as "clicking" ?

Comment: I want to toggle them by «mouseenter» and when I click on them — they behave like normal links (with custom href link).

Comment: So you can add "Active" class on mousenter and use click functionality as stated above, if I am understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code to implement that feature no 1, changing tabs on hover

```
$('.nav-tabs li').hover(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs li a').removeClass('active show');
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active show');
    var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    href = href.substr(1);
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active show');
    $('#'+href).addClass('active show');
});
```

for  next feature add this code to disable click

```
$('.nav-tabs li').click( function(e){
    e.prevenetDefault(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//first, we need to show tab-content on mouseover
$(".nav-link").mouseover( function() {
    $(this).tab("show");
});

// on hovering quickly, need to remove the active class from the related tab panel
$(".nav-link").on("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
    const tabPanelId = e.relatedTarget.getAttribute("href");
    $(tabPanelId).removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers did not work completely. The TonyStar demo quickly breaks when the user hovers semi quickly between tabs. The code has been updated to add a delay to avoid that issue. Add a data-url="" attribute any tab you'd like to link to to website when clicked.

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      $(document).off('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-hover="tab"]');
      $(document).on('mouseenter.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-hover="tab"]', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active') && !$this.hasClass('disabled')) {
          var delay = setTimeout(function() {
            $this.tab('show');
          }, 150);
          $this.data('tab-delay', delay);
        }
      }).on('mouseleave.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-hover="tab"]', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        clearTimeout($this.data('tab-delay'));
      }).on('click', '[data-hover="tab"]', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.data('url');
        if (url) {
          window.location.href = url;
        }
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```